# Facebook widget or just a link out to facebook?

Tags: facebook, widget

Just wondering what thoughts are on using the Facebook widget? Ive had a comment that just using a link out to facebook is a bit old fashioned. My own opinion is that widgets are not nice experience, and a user will just go to facebook if they want to. What do you think?

Comment: Which widget are you referring to?

Comment: For instance the page feed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no denying that Facebook works best in its own environment (not truncated as a widget). FB has invested billions of dollars to optimize the use of their website. Then why offer widgets?

I have had success with widgets on websites that need to impress NEW, UNDECIDED visitors. If a visitor is "checking out" your website and weighing the value of "signing up", subscribing, or any investment -- showing your live Facebook activity is a way to show off your social media activity.

You're correct, ESPUX, visitors already sold to your company will just interface with your FB page on Facebook.com

Showcasing your social media prowess can be a double-edged sword. You better have updated, relevant, and non-damaging content being streamed to your widget. Otherwise, you're making yourself look worse.